# how to add an error message when an integer is input instead of a string

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to add an error when a string is entered instead of an integer. I've looked at other similar posts but when I try and implement it into my code it keeps spitting errors out. I have a number guessing game between 1 and 50 here. Can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 50)

while True:
    try:
    guess = int ( input("Guess a number between 1 and 50: ") )
    break
except ValueError:
    print("Please input a number.")**
  

while guess != number:
    if guess < number:
        print ("You need to guess higher. Try again.")
        guess = int ( input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: ") )
    else:
        print ("You need to guess lower. Try again.")
        guess = int ( input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: "))

print ("You guessed the number correctly!")
```

Comment: It would help if you shared what's the error you're getting. Your indentation is wrong so it's hard to know if that's your actual issue or a formatting problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/6045800)

Comment: The issue is mostly an indentation error as when the code is formatted correctly it works as expected

Comment: @RohithNambiar Not likely as the second loop will still raise an error for wrong input which doesn't sound like the expected behavior. OP is basically asking how to re-ask for input in the second loop

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're asking three times for the exact same input. There is really no need for that and no need for two loops at all. Just set the `guess` to a default value that will never be equal to the number (`None`) and use one single `input`, wrapped with `try/except`:

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 50)
guess = None  

while guess != number:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 50: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input a number.")
    else:
        if guess < number:
            print("You need to guess higher. Try again.")
        elif guess > number:
            print("You need to guess lower. Try again.")

print("You guessed the number correctly!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a while loop for the input statements. Checking if the input(in string format) is numeric and then casting it to int.
Sample code:

```
a = input()
while not a.isnumeric():
    a = input('Enter a valid integer')
a = int(a)
```

The code executes until the value of `a` is an `int`

Answer (score 0):

your code did not work because the indentation is not right

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 50)
while True:
    try:
        guess = int ( input("Guess a number between 1 and 50: ") ) # here
        break # here
    except ValueError: # here
        print("Please input a number.")
  

while guess != number:
    if guess < number:
        print ("You need to guess higher. Try again.")
        guess = int ( input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: ") )
    else:
        print ("You need to guess lower. Try again.")
        guess = int ( input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: "))

print ("You guessed the number correctly!")
```

**Output**

```
Guess a number between 1 and 50: aa
Please input a number.
Guess a number between 1 and 50: 4
You need to guess higher. Try again.
```